# Pouring Water on Lord ganesha in the dream

Tags: scripture, dream

Hi hope someone can help me understand the meaning of my dream I am not able to understand why did I see this particular act in my dream last night.

I dreamt of pouring water on the Lord Ganesha's idol which was made of black rock and there were two idols one is 12 inches and the other idol was of six and a half feet tall. I was shocked by the amount of water it took to pour on these two idols from 5-liter water pot.

Comment: Did you watch Baahubali: conclusion before sleeping or sometime before sleeping? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7XVtMCx1iE

Comment: @Yogi Haha.....